# Machiavelli on making hard decisions

Tags: political-theory, decision-making

Is there anywhere where, in his writings, Machivelli talks about making difficult decisions and how to regard "the greater good"?

Comment: Could you clarify why you assume that Machiavelli did talk about this in the first place?

Comment: In "The Prince", he hinted about it, I think, when he was talking about being feared or loved and talked about being sure not to enspire hatred, only fear. I'm not sure that he did though.

Comment: The quote I remember from "The Prince" was about never implementing directly unpopular policies, but "through agents"

Comment: Chapter 17 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Machiavelli's Books

Although most famous for "The Prince", most of Machiavelli's political theory is laid out in "Discourses on the First 10 Books of Titus Livy".  In Discourses he outlines his views on republics by examining the a treatise by a 1st century Roman historian. The Prince focuses on "principalities" - nations with dictatorial (non-republic) governments.

You can find free PDFs of both on Constitution.org:

- [Discourses on Livy](http://www.constitution.org/mac/disclivy.pdf)
- [The Prince](http://www.constitution.org/mac/prince.pdf)

### Regime and Public Interest

Machiavelli distinguishes between three different types of regimes based on the relationship between nobility and citizens. For each, public good is treated differently. I'll summarize below, but a great synopsis can be found at the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy website](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/machiavelli/#6)

#### Fully Constitutional Republics

A fully constitutional republic is characterized by constant civil conflict between nobility and citizens. That is just to say that their interests collide and the conflict is handled through politics: nobles and citizens can both organize and lobby for their interests through the republic.

In a constitutional republic, the public good is liberty. Good governance means maximizing liberty for everyone in the community (both aristocrats and common citizens).  Rulers should strive to keep both groups engaged in political processes and enact strong laws or institutions to keep either side from dominating the other.

#### Aristocracies

Aristocracies (or what SEP calls "minimally constitutional republics") are regimes where the ruler rules over citizens with limited constitutional protections. The government is strong enough to suppress the ambitions of both nobles and citizens, but the government is (in turn) confined by strong institutions and laws.

In these regimes, the public good is best served by encouraging security. Citizens and nobles have to be protected from the others interests, and in turn both need to be minimally protected from the government.  Rulers should be constantly vigilente, watching the movements of citizens and nobles, while citizens and nobles need to develop strong laws and institutions to protect themselves (both) from the government.

#### Principalities

Principalities are the subject of the "Prince". These are governments mostly unrestrained by a constitution, where the government (or "prince") can rule without an institution hampering them.  In these regimes, there really is no notion of public good. The prince is effectively a dictator, and a successful prince is one that stays in power (or enhances his power).

One of Machiavelli's points in "The Prince" is that this kind of regime is not unilateral: the Prince cannot simply dictate how things will go and expect them to work.  Without strong laws, institutions, or class interest to compel cooperation the Prince can either be "feared or loved".  He can encourage cooperation by being just and generous (encouraging people to follow out of love) or by being strong (encouraging people to follow out of fear).